# How to get wlan device name with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess, shlex

I want only the wlan device name at a linux system with python. I could get the device name with shell scripting:

```
echo /sys/class/net/*/wireless | awk -F'/' '{ print $5 }'
```

So i want to use this at python with `subprocess`.

```
import shlex
import subprocess

def main():
    echo = shlex.split('echo /sys/class/net/*/wireless')
    echo_proc = subprocess.Popen(echo, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    awk = shlex.split("awk -F'/' '{ print $5 }'")
    awk_proc = subprocess.Popen(awk, stdin=echo_proc.stdout)
    print(awk_proc.stdout)
```

But I get only `None` as output. If it is possible, I would prefer a solution with `subprocess.run()`. So I replaced `Popen` with `run`. But then I get the error message `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'fileno'`.

Comment: Have you tried just using subprocess.run?

Comment: Yes, but then I get the error message ``AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'fileno'``. I replaced only Popen with run.

Comment: Show how you did it. Sounds like you passed in the wrong thing.

Comment: It looks like my current code except ``Popen`` is replaced with ``run``.

Comment: I mean edit your question with actual code. If something isn't working, describing what you think is important isn't really a good technique. If you knew what was important, you wouldn't be asking on SO. Please be specific and detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type glob and a pathname expansion by shell will be a headache.
In my environment, the following snippet works:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('echo /sys/class/net/*/wireless', shell=True)
```

But the following returns an empty string:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['echo', '/sys/class/net/*/wireless'], shell=True)
```

Then please try the following as a starting point:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('echo /sys/class/net/*/wireless | awk -F"/" "{ print \$5 }"', shell=True)
```

which will bring your desired output.

[Update]
If you want to assign a variable to the output above, please try:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.run('echo /sys/class/net/*/wireless | awk -F"/" "{ print \$5 }"', shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
wlan = proc.stdout.decode("utf8").rstrip("\n")
print(wlan)
```

BTW if you don't stick to the `subprocess` module, why don't you go with a native way as:

```
import glob
list = glob.glob('/sys/class/net/*/wireless')
for elm in list:
    print(elm.split('/')[4])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. But how do I get the result form subprocess.run? ``stdout`` is None. I get the ``CompletedProcess``.

Comment: If my script properly prints the desired output on the terminal and you want to capture it to a variable, please try the updated answer. Hope it will work.